# DataContext name of WPFToolkit DataGrid shows in columns header background

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datacontext, wpftoolkit

I've got a strange problem with WPFToolkit `DataGrid` - after disabling `AutoGenerateColumns`, after adding only 1, narrow column, in the background of column headers appears full name of `DataContext`. It doesn't behave like a column - I can't neither resize or disable it.

Previously I didn't know about this problem, because I had few wide enough columns, but know this is a serius problem.

This is my code:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <model:ShowUnitViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
            <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static lang:Unit.Name}" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    </toolkit:DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved.

The reason was wrong binding in DataGridColumnHeader template - I've created my own template with ContentPresenter without binding and works fine.

Previously was something like binding {Binding} in the content which caused the problem